# Owncloud в качестве хранилища фаилов для веб-сервиса

Tags: php, owncloud

Хочу использовать owncloud как хранилище файлов, а к файлам получать доступ через мой веб-сервис (php). Но к сожалению нигде не нашел примеров удаленного взаимодействия с owncloud (авторизация, список файлов и т.д).
Как это можно сделать? Видел они используют протокол webdav для удаленного монтирования, но не знаю подойдет ли это для меня и не знаю как с этим протоколом работать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я помню, webdav в owncloud реализован средствами самого php.
Хранение файлов же там настраиваемое и можно в качестве backend использовать тот же amazon s3 или его альтернативу riak-cs(основано на базе riak, умеет работать по s3 протоколу).

А дальше уже зависит от ваших потребностей:
- если нужно дёргать базу прав с owncloud - лучше всего писать плагин для owncloud.
- если нужно просто дёргать файлы - лучше писать надстройку над хранилищем.

Comment: т.е по сути я буду взаимодействовать с неким модулем (плагином) на стороне owncloud который может вытаскивать мне файлы конкретного пользователя?                                                           надеюсь в плагин можно будет добавить авторизацию (для получения списка всех файлов пользователя)

Comment: Да, именно так и следует реализовывать.